# i want to change the background color of a div on hover except the icon part of the div?

Tags: css

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 content1">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-object pull-left">
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-desktop"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h3> WEB <span class="greenText">DESIGNING</span></h3>
            <p class="pull-right">Do you need a web site for your business? Not sure where to begin? We can help you create the web site of your dreams.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the background color of `.content1` except `.media-object` that is inside the `.content1`

Comment: Wouldnt just change the colour of `.media-body` work? Can you provide your css or what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can just target the following class .media-body

```
.media-body:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Kindly check www.azmtech.com. i just want to change the background color of whole div on hover except the <a> tag background color.